# Как использовать ГСЧ с++11 в классе?

Tags: c++

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> rng(1, 2);
```

Имеется такой генератор, находится он в main.
Как я могу использовать этот генератор в виде int a = `rng(gen)` в классе?
В заголовочный файл я не могу вставить в таком виде, в исполняемый вставляется, но правильно ли я использую его? [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в данном случае у меня есть еще 3 метода класса, где мне надо число генерировать случайно, это получается, что эти 3 строчки пишутся 3 раза, но я на 90% уверен, что это делается не так. Мне нужно передавать в конструктор класса этот генератор или как?

Comment: Можно, и так, и эдак - как вам больше нравится. Если вам может потребоваться какая-то особо хитрая генерация - передавайте свой генератор/распределение, если нет - мне кажется, можно особо не волноваться...

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде

Answer (score 3):

Разберемся по порядку.

```
 random_device rd;
```

Это - источник случайности, т.н. "зерна". По сути дела это генератор псевдослучайной последовательности целых чисел c равномерным распределением, в большинстве реализаций имеющи предетеминированное начало.

```
 mt19937 gen(rd());
```

Это наш ГСЧ, в данном случае тип `mt19937` - ["Вихрь" Мерсенна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0) Выражение  `rd()` - это "зерно", seed для генератора ПСЕВДОслучайных чисел. Передача его таким образом обычно делает его предсказуемым, чаще к зерну добавляют время или другие внешние факторы. Например:

```
std::mt19937::result_type seed = rd() ^ (
        (std::mt19937::result_type)
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ).count() +
        (std::mt19937::result_type)
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ).count() );

std::mt19937 gen(seed);
```

Почему генератор по умолчанию был полностью детерминирован? В целях отладки и тестирования, ситуация та же что и со старинными `srand\rand`. Например, в новых версиях GCC (> 9.2) `random_device` был "исправлен" и вышеуказанная "рандомизация" может быть лишней. И, наконец,

```
 uniform_int_distribution<> rng(1, 2);
```

Это функция распределения. Можно иметь несколько генреаторов с различными зернами но использовать функции распределения с любым из них. ГСЧ хранит свое предыдущиее состояние, поэтому для независимых событий стоит использовать отдельные генераторы, но распределения можно использовать повторно. Выражение `rng(gen)` возвращает новое значения распределения rng для генератора gen.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как вы поняли из текста вопроса, что у автора вопроса `std::random_device` "был полностью детерминирован"?

Comment: *"обычно делает его предсказуемым"* – но он сделан как раз для генерации недетерминированного сида, хотя в некоторых реализациях может быть детерминирован, т.е. не "обычно", а "иногда"

Comment: @dlm0n по факту - все кроме самых последних GCC\MinGW(на этот счет написано приличное число отчетов от ошибках\несоответствиях, ссылка на версию GCC не из головы взята), на некоторых платформах - для всех. К тому же в некоторых случаях только первое значение не детерминировано, последующие зависят от начального.Ряд вендоров ОС\компиляторов предпочитают это делать так из вышеуказанных корпоративных соображений